# Access root directory?

Tags: fastboot, boot

Assuming that I am not able to start up my phone due to a file that is missing on the file system. Would it be possible to get to my phone's root directory on my computer and to place the missing file?

Maybe by using fastboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you have a custom recovery that supports adb / root, you can boot into it and use adb to remount `/system` as read-write and push the missing file over.  But otherwise you don't have access to most of the phone.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!! I have managed to get the cmd-based recovery running. Now I can finnaly use adb to get the file which is missing to its place. The only problem is I am not sure there I could get the file i need.

Comment: @NitramRelisch I'd recommend looking over at XDA -- their Wildfire S subforum is a good place to start, specifically [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1325730).

Comment: okay, I'll try that, thx for ALL ur help!